# Google Play filter issue: This application is available to over 0 devices

Tags: android, manifest, device

I'm running into the same problem that several other stackoverflow users have seen - "Supported devices: 0" or "This application is available to over 0 devices".

This is an application that has been live in Google Play for over 6 months, and I'm trying to release an update. It previously supported over 1,000 devices, and now supports 0 - I can no longer find it in Google Play. I didn't change the manifest during the update (other than the version numbers), so I can't see why it's having trouble.

I have already looked into the other solutions found on stackoverflow:

1. I have updated my Android SDK and Eclipse
2. I have confirmed there are no JAR files in the /src folder
3. The APK is ACTIVATED

Does anyone have any suggestions as to the possible problems, based on the below manifest.xml file?

Many thanks in advance!

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="*****"
    android:versionCode="10"
    android:sharedUserId="*****"
    android:installLocation="preferExternal"
    android:versionName="1.10" >
    <supports-screens
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:anyDensity="true"/>  

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="8" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>


<uses-configuration android:reqTouchScreen="finger"/>

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch"
               android:required="false" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen"
               android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:name="*****" 
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:screenOrientation ="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"   
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:screenOrientation ="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"        
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".SplashScreen">
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

      <activity android:name=".GameActivity" 
          android:screenOrientation ="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"></activity>

        <activity android:name=".SettingActivity" android:screenOrientation ="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"></activity>
        <activity android:name="ChoosePuzzle" android:screenOrientation ="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"></activity>

         <activity android:name=".HelpScreen" android:screenOrientation ="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"></activity>
         <activity android:name=".Shop"  android:screenOrientation ="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"></activity>         

        <activity android:name=".HomeScreen"  android:screenOrientation ="portrait" android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"></activity>   

       <meta-data android:name="com.mobclix.APPLICATION_ID"
             android:value="*****"/>

        <activity android:name="com.mobclix.android.sdk.MobclixBrowserActivity" android:screenOrientation ="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"/>
        <activity android:name=".ChoosePuzzleScreen" android:screenOrientation ="portrait" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".ChooseBatchScreen" android:screenOrientation ="portrait" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"  ></activity>    
        <activity android:name=".WebViewActivity" android:screenOrientation ="portrait" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"  ></activity>

<activity android:name="com.openfeint.internal.ui.IntroFlow"
  android:label="IntroFlow"
  android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
  android:theme="@style/OFNestedWindow"/> <activity
  android:name="com.openfeint.api.ui.Dashboard"
  android:label="Dashboard"
  android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
  android:theme="@style/OFNestedWindow"/>
<activity android:name="com.openfeint.internal.ui.Settings"
  android:label="Settings"
  android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
  android:theme="@style/OFNestedWindow"/>
<activity android:name="com.openfeint.internal.ui.NativeBrowser"
  android:label="NativeBrowser"
  android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
  android:theme="@style/OFNestedWindow"/>           

        <activity android:name="com.facebook.android.FacebookActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.facebook.android.GraphExplorer"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

        <activity android:name="com.facebook.android.IntentUriHandler">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:scheme="fbgraphex" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.facebook.android.Places"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
     </application>
</manifest>
```

EDIT: I have also run aapt to test, with the following results:

```
package: name='*****' versionCode='8' versionName='1.8'
sdkVersion:'8'
targetSdkVersion:'8'
uses-permission:'android.permission.INTERNET'
uses-permission:'android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS'
uses-permission:'android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE'
uses-permission:'android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE'
uses-permission:'android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE'
uses-permission:'android.permission.WAKE_LOCK'
uses-configuration: reqTouchScreen='3'
uses-feature-not-required:'android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch'
uses-feature:'android.hardware.touchscreen'
application-label:'*****'
application-icon-120:'res/drawable-hdpi/icon.png'
application-icon-160:'res/drawable-hdpi/icon.png'
application-icon-240:'res/drawable-hdpi/icon.png'
application-icon-320:'res/drawable-hdpi/icon.png'
application: label='*****' icon='res/drawable-hdpi/icon.png'
launchable-activity: name='*****.SplashScreen'  label='*****' icon=''
uses-feature:'android.hardware.screen.portrait'
main
other-activities
supports-screens: 'small' 'normal' 'large'
supports-any-density: 'true'
locales: '--_--'
densities: '120' '160' '240' '320'
```

Comment: Can you give a general idea of what you changed with this update, anything that might be relevant? I'm not exactly sure what, but it might be good to have an idea what you did. Does "required device features" on the publish page list anything?

Comment: I actually made a fair number of changes internally - the app was originally built just for a specific few screen resolutions, and I changed it to work with all.

Comment: @Tim On the Product Details page, under Supported Devices, it displays: 
Screen layouts: SMALL NORMAL LARGE XLARGE
Required device features
android.hardware.screen.portrait
android.hardware.touchscreen

Comment: Have you found a solution? I'm having the same problem, nothing makes sense and Google Play support is absolutely useless with their generic replies with links to documentation about filters.

Comment: Never truly found a solution. But after making a ton of changes for a week, and then about a month of talking with Google Play support (and getting no help), I recently tried submitting it again (with no changes) and it went without a hitch.

Comment: So did you solve your problem?

Comment: Previously came across this type of issue. [Check here for some solutions.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34237774/after-publishing-my-application-on-play-store-i-cant-download-it-from-any-phone/34237943?noredirect=1)

Answer (score 0):

Change the android:targetSdkVersion="8"